# Structural Equation modeling

Tags: r

This is my model and the errors I'm having. I am also getting `NA` in the results.

```
 model <- '
          accessibilité  =~ desser_transp2+zone3
          littératie     =~ lit_form_med + lit_suivre_inst + lit_lire_sante + lit_lire_medoc + lit_aide_doc_admi
          attitudes      =~ favor_vaccin2 + refus_vaccin2
          discrimination =~ violence2 + violence_circonst2
          vacci_ROR_yn    ~ accessibilité + littératie + attitudes + discrimination
          accessibilité  ~~ discrimination
          littératie     ~~ attitudes
          '

fit <- cfa(model, data=GDV,estimator="WLSMV", std.lv = TRUE)
```

```
Warning messages:
1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
    does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
    (= 4.153749e-19) is close to zero. This may be a symptom that the
    model is not identified.
2: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative
```

What does "does not appear to be positive definite mean"?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Without sight of your data, it might be difficult to help you.  A singular covariance matrix indicates that you have linear dependencies amongst your covariates.  In other words, one (or more) predictors can be constructed as a linear comination of other covariates.  From what you've posted so far, `favor_vaccin2` and `refus_vaccin2` *might* be cadidates.  Are respondants either "favor"ing or "refus"ing with no other option?  If so, `favor_vaccin2 == !refus_vaccin2` and that could be a linear dependency.

Comment: Further, this does not appear to be complete, syntactically-correct code: the whole `model <-` block does not appear to be within a string or a function call, so it is unclear how it is structured. It is typically better to copy the code itself without all of the console-inserted `+`s, as those make it difficult to differentiate user code and console representation. The `reprex` package can help with this, if need be.

Comment: It appears this may be a Heywood case in structural equation modeling. I'd recommend posting this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/